# Como puedo solamente affichar el contenido de una List

Tags: c#, webservice, lista

Tengo un servicio Web en el cual el resultado es una `<List>`. Puedo sacar el resultado sin problemas. Lo que estoy buscando hacer es que solamente me muestre el resultado dependiendo que el valor del resultado se sea igual a 1.

Aquí está la estructura del servicio Web y lo que muestra en el resultado:

```
<Response>
    <List>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">Q9Row1</anyType>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">Q9Comment1</anyType>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">Q10Row1</anyType>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">Q10Comment1</anyType>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">Q11Row1</anyType>

    </List>
</Response>
<Response>
    <List>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">1</anyType>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">2</anyType>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">2</anyType>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">1</anyType>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">1</anyType>
    </List>
</Response>
```

Lo que yo deseo es que si en `<Q9Row1>` el resultado es 1 en `<anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">1</anyType>` me muestre el resultado. Si el resultado es otro que 1. Que el programa no me muestre nada.

Aqui esta la forma la cual llamo originalmente el servicio antes de obtener lo que menciono.

```
public static string arrayToString(object[] array)//overload
{
    string s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
    {
        s += array[i].ToString() + " , ";
    }
    if (s.Length > 3) { s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 3); }
    return s;
}

WebRefernce.DashboardSoapClient db = new WebRefernce.DashboardSoapClient();

WebRefernce.Response[] resp = db.GetResponse();

for (int i = 0; i < resp.Length; ++i)
{
    textBox1.Text += Form1.arrayToString(resp[i].List);
}
```

Lo que originalmente hago es solamente afichar el resultado. Ahora busco en aficharlo pero que solamente muestre cuando  = 1

Tanto como Q9Row1 y 1 son valores de la lista. El Q9Row1 es el encabezado de la respuesta y el 1 es el resultado de esta. Pero ambos son valores no propiedades.

Inclui un pantallazo del resultado de resp.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El primer pantallazo muestra como aficha el Q9Row1 en el primer string que requiero.

Este segundo pantallazo muestra cuando el resultado pasa por segunda vez en el `for resp.Length` y ahi me muestra el 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto en C#?

Comment: Sería bueno que digas que hay en resp? Tal vez debugueando puedas poner un pantallazo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes filtrar los resultados utilizando LinQ, suponiendo que recibes la lista en una variable de tipo `List<ClaseServicioWeb>`:

```
List<ClaseServicioWeb> listaObtenida = (List<ClaseServicioWeb>)listaObtenida.Where(t => t.Q9Row1 == "1").ToList();
```

Nota: debes hacer uso de la referencia `System.linq` agregándola al inicio de tu archivo con `using System.Linq;`

## Actualización

Cambiando el ciclo `for` por un `foreach` podremos obtener el resuldato deseado:

```
WebRefernce.Response[] resp = db.GetResponse();

foreach(var item in resp.Where(t => t.CampoQueDeseasFiltrar == "1").ToList())
{
    textBox1.Text += Form1.arrayToString(item.List);
}
```

Donde el `CampoQueDeseasFiltrar` lo debes cambiar por el nombre del atributo que deseas filtar

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, al hacer lo que me sugieres me aparece el siguiente error:  does not contain a definition for 'Q6Row1' and no extension method 'Q6Row1' acception a first argument

Comment: Ok, actualizaré mi respuesta, me parece que hace falta un casteo

Comment: Listo, quedo en espera de tus comentarios.

Comment: sigo teniendo el mismo error en t.Q9Row1 "'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Q6Row1' and no extension method 'Q6Row1' acception a first argument of type 'System.Array''

Comment: Me parece extraño que aparezca `Q6Row1` cuando no en la definición del servicio no existe un campo con este nombre, ¿son todos los campos del servicio o estás omitiendo alguno? Pregunto esto debido a que los atributos de la clase deben coincidir con los recibidos en el servicio, a menos que los pongas como `Nullable`

Comment: es Q9Row1 no Q6Row1. me equivoque al escribir en vez de copiar y pegar. No estoy omitiendo nungun campo. El parametro es bien Q9Row1 y me aparece el mismo error.

Comment: Ah ok ok ntp, eso queda más claro y sencillo para responder la pregunta, veamos, en tu servicio recibes un campo llamado `Q9Row1`, ese campo lo recibes en una clase cuando lo metes a la `List<>` entonces, en tu clase, ¿cómo se llama ese campo?

Comment: Hola gracias nuevamente, acabo de editar mi pregunta añadiendo el codigo completo de como llamo el servicio y de lo que busco hacer. Espero tus comentarios.

Comment: Cuando haces esto `resp[i].List`, ¿qué variales llevas en ese array?

Comment: Cuando lo hago me muestra el numero de objetos en el array. En mi caso me muestra 5 y si lo expando me muestra [0] "Q9Row1"
Al hacer el cambio que me sugieres con el foreach el campo que deseo filtrar es el mismo Q9Row1. Si pongo esto me dara el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez, así te funcione:

```
for (int i = 0; i < resp.Length; ++i)
{
    if (resp[i].ToString().Equals("1"))
        textBox1.Text += Form1.arrayToString(resp[i].List);
}
```

Comment: Hola, al modificar el arrayToString usango el Equals("1"). Me va a pedir que el resultado entero sea igual a 1 y no solamente un elemento. Dado a que tengo 5 elementos en la lista, solo quiero validad 1 de ellos que sea igual a 1

Comment: Entonces creo que no te estas dando a entender bien que es lo que quieres hacer. Por favor dime que y como te retorna los valores resp y despues de que te retorna esos valores que necesitas hacer? Es que al final ese 'Q9Row1' no sé si es una propiedad o un valor

Comment: Me devuelve como valores "Q9Row1". El Q9row1 son los encabezados de las respuuestas del resp. El Q9Row1 es la respuesta del encabezado. Lo que necesito es hayar ambos, el emcabezado que es Q9Row 1 y la repsuesta que seria 1
Ambos son valores y no propiedades

Comment: Sigo sin entenderte bien, si pudieras poner un pantallazo de lo que te retorna resp tal vez pueda ayudar mejor con la respuesta. De igual forma y según lo que logro entender he actualizado mi anterior respuesta

Comment: Ya inclui el pantallazo del resultado de resp

Comment: Excelente, entonces se debe recorrer ese resultado y buscar dentro de cada string si tiene un 1 incluido en el texto, si es así se debe retornar todo el string, si no, ese string no se retorna, es así lo que necesitas?

Comment: exacto, tiene que recorrer el resultado de Q9Row1 que es el primer string y el segundo string es 1. solo debe retornar si las condiciones se respetan si no, el no retorna nada

Comment: cuando hago el debug, y paso la segunda vez por el for, el List me da el valor de 1. La primera vez me muestra Q9Row1 y la segunda vez que ejecuta me regresa el valor de 1

Comment: Cuando dices el segundo string es 1 a qué te refieres? porque yo veo que el segundo string dice: Q9Comment1, por ende entonces este string si lo retorna. De hecho todos los que tienes ahí en el pantallazo si los retornaría porque tienen un 1 en el string de cada uno.

Comment: Ya actualize la pregunta incluyendo el segundo pantallazo. Cuando el resp.Length pasa por segunda vez, me muestra ya el 1 que espero en el resultado

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52493/discussion-between-alonso-fallas-and-a-arancibia).

Comment: Hola, no habia visto este ultimo mensaje. Dime si puedes seguir la conversacion por medio del chat?

Comment: Claro, ahí te espero.